# Failing to substitude

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("12345678901","bob")]
[InlineData("12345678902", "alice")]
public void Customer_Registration_Should_Succeed(string identityId, string name)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer(identityId, name);

    _customerRepository.Add(customer).Returns(customer);

    var customerService = new CustomerService(_customerRepository);

    var expectedCustomer = customerService.Register(identityId, name);

    Assert.Equal(expectedCustomer, customer);

}
```

I have the above test code.

Here is the service:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public Customer Register(IdentityId identityId, Name name)
    {
        var customer = new Customer(identityId, name);
        var newCustomer = _customerRepository.Add(customer);

        return newCustomer;
    }
}
```

And below is the repository:

```
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    IList<Customer> _customers;

    public CustomerRepository()
    {
        _customers = new List<Customer>();
    }

    public Customer Add(Customer customer)
    {
        _customers.Add(customer);

        return customer;
    }
}
```

But I get null reference exception.

```
Assert.Equal(expectedCustomer, customer);
```

and assertion fails. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two separate instances are being created by,

the method under test.

```
public Customer Register(IdentityId identityId, Name name)
{
    var customer = new Customer(identityId, name); //<-- HERE
    var newCustomer = _customerRepository.Add(customer);

    return newCustomer;
}
```

and the test

```
//...

Customer customer = new Customer(identityId, name); // <--HERE

_customerRepository.Add(customer).Returns(customer);

//...
```

Problem is that the instance in the test is used as an argument for configuring the substitute.

The substitute will expect the exact instance from the setup but the method under test is passing its own instance which will cause the substitute to return null as the arguments do not match.

An option would be to setup the substitute to return the argument that was passed to the invoked member.

For example

```
_customerRepository.Add(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(_ => _.Arg<Customer>());
```

Which can be asserted as necessary

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("12345678901","bob")]
[InlineData("12345678902", "alice")]
public void Customer_Registration_Should_Succeed(string identityId, string name) {
    //Arrange
    _customerRepository.Add(Arg.Any<Customer>()).Returns(_ => _.Arg<Customer>());
    var customerService = new CustomerService(_customerRepository);

    //Act
    var actual = customerService.Register(identityId, name);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    Assert.AreEqual(actual.IdentityId, identityId);
    Assert.AreEqual(actual.Name, name);

    //Check received with the arg:
    _customerRepository.Received().Add(actual);
}
```